# After I compile mrpt manually, I have a trouble with build mrpt files

Tags: mobile-robot-toolkit

I'm trying to combine every system with `ros` but before that I wanted to check whether it works well or not so I run file on `CLion`, and I got these errors.

```
/home/ian/Downloads/clion-2017.2.1/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/ian/CLionProjects/mrqt --target mrpt -- -j 4
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable mrpt
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_imgcodecs3.so.3.2, needed by /usr/local/lib/libmrpt-base.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_imgproc3.so.3.2, needed by /usr/local/lib/libmrpt-base.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_core3.so.3.2, needed by /usr/local/lib/libmrpt-base.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/local/lib/libmrpt-base.so: undefined reference to `cvLoadImage'
/usr/local/lib/libmrpt-base.so: undefined reference to `cvConvertImage'
/usr/local/lib/libmrpt-base.so: undefined reference to `cvReleaseImage'
/usr/local/lib/libmrpt-base.so: undefined reference to `cvSplit'
/usr/local/lib/libmrpt-base.so: undefined reference to `cvMatchTemplate'
/usr/local/lib/libmrpt-base.so: undefined reference to `_IplImage::_IplImage(cv::Mat const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libmrpt-base.so: undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
/usr/local/lib/libmrpt-base.so: undefined reference to `cvSmooth'
/usr/local/lib/libmrpt-base.so: undefined reference to `cvFlip'
/usr/local/lib/libmrpt-base.so: undefined reference to `cvGetSize'
/usr/local/lib/libmrpt-base.so: undefined reference to `cvCvtColor'
/usr/local/lib/libmrpt-base.so: undefined reference to `cvCircle'
/usr/local/lib/libmrpt-base.so: undefined reference to `cvGetQuadrangleSubPix'
/usr/local/lib/libmrpt-base.so: undefined reference to `cvRemap'
/usr/local/lib/libmrpt-base.so: undefined reference to `cvLine'
/usr/local/lib/libmrpt-base.so: undefined reference to `cvSaveImage'
/usr/local/lib/libmrpt-base.so: undefined reference to `cvCopy'
/usr/local/lib/libmrpt-base.so: undefined reference to `cvCloneImage'
/usr/local/lib/libmrpt-base.so: undefined reference to `cvSetImageROI'
/usr/local/lib/libmrpt-base.so: undefined reference to `cvEqualizeHist'
/usr/local/lib/libmrpt-base.so: undefined reference to `cvMinMaxLoc'
/usr/local/lib/libmrpt-base.so: undefined reference to `cvMerge'
/usr/local/lib/libmrpt-base.so: undefined reference to `cvResize'
/usr/local/lib/libmrpt-base.so: undefined reference to `cvUndistort2'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/mrpt.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'mrpt' failed
make[3]: *** [mrpt] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/mrpt.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/mrpt.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/mrpt.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/mrpt.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'mrpt' failed
make: *** [mrpt] Error 2
```

When I first compiled it, it was fine, but later I had some issues with `mrpt` header files, I deleted them all and compiled it manually, and this problem happened. Can I get some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a mix of different MRPT versions installed in your system.

I don't recommend doing `sudo make install` unless you have a strong reason to do it; just compiling the project in its own build directory will generate a `MRPTConfig.cmake` file, which allows CMake to find MRPT from ROS or whatever other user project.

If CMake doesn't find it automatically, just set the environment variable `export MRPT_DIR=/home/xxx/path/to/mrpt/build` and it will work.

Your problem right now is cleaning all the mess that may be under `/usr/local/`. Take a look at that directory and if the only project you have `make install`ed is MRPT, I strongly recommend deleting it with `sudo rm -fr /usr/local/*`.

If you have other projects there... well... you must run `sudo make uninstall` from the MRPT build dir, then manually make sure there are no remaining files.

The link error against OpenCV also looks like CMake configured the project for one opencv version, then another one got installed (perhaps via ROS packages?). 
After doing the clean up of `/usr/local` mentioned above, delete your current MRPT CMake build directory and start from scratch again.